# Indexed KeyValueMap

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, functional-style, map

I have been trying to figure it out and I am probably very close, but I have spent 2 hours without sucess. I have the expression below

```
MapIndexed[
 geg[First[#2], 
   Total[KeyValueMap[fef[#1, #2, mem] &, #1]]] &, {<|a -> b, 
   c -> d|>, <|e -> f|>}]
```

which produces

```
{geg[1, fef[a, b, mem] + fef[c, d, mem]], geg[2, fef[e, f, mem]]}
```

I want to have the position of the association in the list `{<|a -> b, 
       c -> d|>, <|e -> f|>}` passed both to `geg` and `fef`

That is, I want the result to be

```
{geg[1, fef[a, b, 1, mem] + fef[c, d, 1, mem]], geg[2, fef[e, f, 2, mem]]}
```

Comment: `MapIndexed[f[#[[1]], #[[2]], #2]&, Normal[assoc]]`?

Comment: @b3m2a1 I couldn't get this to work really, as it gives the position of the rule inside the association (after converting it to a list of rules), rather than the position of the association in my list of associations

Comment: Ah I misread the question. The shortest thing then is probably `Table[KeyValueMap[f[##, i]&, assocs[[i]]], {i, Length@assocs}]`

Comment: @b3m2a1 This does indeed work and preserves the association structure (compared to your first proposal). If you were to post it as an answer, I would upvote it, but then I will need some time to decide on which to be the accepted answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MapIndexed[Function[{v, k}, 
  geg[First[k], Total[KeyValueMap[fef[#1, #2, First[k], mem] &, v]]]],
 {<|a -> b, c -> d|>, <|e -> f|>}]
```

> {geg[1, fef[a, b, 1, mem] + fef[c, d, 1, mem]],
>    geg[2, fef[e, f, 2, mem]]}

Or, slightly more readable version:

```
MapIndexed[Function[{v, k}, 
  geg[First[k], 
     Total[KeyValueMap[Function[{key, val}, fef[key, val, First[k], mem]], v]]]],
  {<| a -> b, c -> d|>, <|e -> f|>}]
```

> same result

With a minimal change in OP's code:

```
MapIndexed[geg[i = First[#2], Total[KeyValueMap[fef[#1, #2, i, mem] &, #1]]] &,
   {<|a -> b, c -> d|>, <|e -> f|>}]
```

> same result

and, without `KeyValueMap`:

```
MapIndexed[geg[i = First[#2], Total[fef[##, i, mem] & @@@ Normal[#]]] &, 
 {<|a -> b, c -> d|>, <|e -> f|>}]
```

> same result

Comment: I don't really understand how this works, can you explain it shortly (it might also be because it is past midnight here).

Comment: @ThunderBiggi, just used  `Function[{x,y}, foo[x,y]]`  with named slots instead of `foo[#1,#2]&`  to avoid slots `#1` and `#2` in the first argument of `MapIndexed` and in `KeyValueMap`.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realise this is allowed